# How do I handle "/" in CSV files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code should load a CSV file, and for each field do something.

For example, the file contains: `/help_desk_idle/`

In my code I need to use:

```
b.image(:src, value).click       # Value is the "/help_desk_idle/" from csv
```

I get an exception in `assert_exists':

```
Unable to locate element, using :src, "/help_desk_idl"
```

The code is:

```
require 'csv'
require 'watir'
require 'rubygems'
Watir::Browser.default = 'ie'
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("data2.csv", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>';', :row_sep =>:auto) do |row|
  type = row[0]
  value = row[1]


  if type == "image"
    puts value
    b.image(:src, value).click
    p b.down_load_time
    sleep 3
```

Comment: Also some CSV you are trying to parse.

Comment: see above my csv and code also i get the following error: in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using :src, "/help_desk_idle/"

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct.